# Derivaiton of maximum deflection of a cantilever beam with intermediate load

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, beam

I am trying to derive the maximum deflection of a cantilever beam. **L** is the length of the beam and **a** is the where force is applied.

For the case 0<x<a, I use the method below and it gives me the same result of well known formulas.
$$M \left( x \right) ={\it Heaviside} \left( a-x \right) F \left( a-x
 \right)$$

$$\delta=\int_{0}^{a}\!{\frac {M \left( x \right) \partial  \left( M
 \left( x \right)  \right) }{EI\partial  \left( F \right) }}\,{\rm d}x
$$

For case a<x<L, which method should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

We calculate the deflection $\delta_a$ and $\theta_a \ \delta_a=\frac{Fa^3}{3EI} \\ \theta_a=\frac{Fa^2}{2EI}$ .

For any point x,  a<x<L we add the slope times*(x -a): $\ \theta*(x-a)$ , while noting the slope doesn't chang past point a, along the beam,to the deflection and we get:

$$\delta= \frac{Fa^2}{6EI}(3x-a)$$